# Try catch execution

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, try-catch, console-application, continue

My requirement is to have a foreach loop inside the try block like below:

```
Try
Foreach file in folder1
line 1
line 2 // throw exception
line 3 
line 4
End Foreach
Catch Exception
   // do error logging
```

my requirement is whenever an exception occurs inside the foreach loop, the execution should not be terminated. For example, 
1.File1 will be processed 
2.File 2 should be processed, but due to some error , the catch stmt will be exceuted to log error information
3.Eventhough error occurred, file 3 should be processed 
Please suggest me the Vb.net code to proceed above steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `Try ... Catch` block inside the `For Each` block, not outside:

```
For Each file In folder1
Try
    ' line 1 '
    ' line 2 ' // throw exception
    ' line 3 '
    ' line 4 '
Catch ex As Exception
    ' error logging '
End Try
Next file
```

<del>And, by the way, the requirements that you posted are contradictory. You want that "the execution *should* be terminated" if your processing throws exceptions. However "even though error occurred, file 3 should be processed", which suggests that the execution *should not* be terminated.</del>

This implementation doesn't terminate the loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach file in folder1
  Try
    line 1
    line 2 // throw exception
    line 3
  Catch Exception
    // do error logging
  End Try
End Foreach
```

You need to put the Try/Catch Block in the ForEach Loop as the first Excpetion is going to end the loop

Comment: Don't want to be nitpicking, but there's no such thing like `End Foreach`. :-)

Comment: I know was just to lazy to make it real code like you did ^^